# Tensorflow server always bound to localhost

Tags: tensorflow

clusterspec.json

```
{ "worker":
 [ "192.168.190.5:2222"
 , "192.168.190.6:2222"
 , "192.168.190.8:2222"
 ]
,"master":
 [ "192.168.190.9:2222" ]
}
```

worker.py

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf

with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
   clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=0)
#task_index is set to 0,1,or 2 for the different workers
```

master.py

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf

with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
    clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    x = tf.mul(a, b)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
    y = tf.mul(a, b)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="master", task_index=0)
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
    print "here"
    print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

The master hangs at 
    sess.run([x,y])

I have noticed that when I execute worker.py on all the workers, I always get this message:

```
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206]   Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job master -> {192.168.190.9:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {localhost:2222,  192.168.190.6:2222, 192.168.190.8:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:203] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
```

So, it is always binding to the local interface, and not 192.168.190.x. Is this the correct behavior? Could someone please explain why the master hangs?

----SIMPLIFIED CODE BASED ON THE COMMENTS---

clusterspec.json

```
{ "worker":
 [ "192.168.190.5:2222"]
}
```

worker.py

```
same as above
```

master.py

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf

with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
    clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    x = tf.mul(a, b)

with tf.Session('grpc://192.168.190.5:2222') as sess:
    print "here"
    print(sess.run([x]))
```

As before, master.py hangs on

```
sess.run([x])
```

One observation:

```
dev@enterprise-3:~$ ps ax | grep master.py
7986 pts/1    Sl+    0:01 python master.py
8008 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto master.py

dev@enterprise-1:~$ ps ax | grep worker.py
7952 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto worker.py
```

`worker.py` doesn't seem to persist..

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you running the `worker.py` script on each of the machines? That is to say, are you running `worker.py --task_index=0` (or however you're configuring it) on the machine with address `192.168.190.5`?

Comment: Yes, running worker.py on machines with IP address 192.168.190.5, 192.168.190.6, and 192.168.190.8, with task_index=0,1, and 2, respectively.

Comment: The standard behavior is for each TensorFlow server to listen on `0.0.0.0:port` (i.e. all interfaces), so it should be able to accept connections from the other hosts. If you start a single-process server on one machine, and try to connect to it from a `tf.Session("grpc://...")` running on another machine, does that work?

Comment: Please look at the simplified example. Still didn't work.

Comment: If I read your simplified example correctly, you define jobs `"master"` and `"worker"` in `cluster`, but only start a server in `worker.py`. This will hang because the server running at `192.168.190.5` will block waiting for a server to come up at `192.168.190.9`. Try removing the `"master"` job from `clusterspec.json` to see if that works.

Comment: I see. Okay, removed `master` from `clusterspec.json` and the result remains the same. `master.py` still hangs :-(

Comment: Here is the output from `worker.py` showing that no `master` exists in `clusterspec.json`                                                                                                  `dev@enterprise-3:~$ python worker.py 
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {localhost:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:203] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222`

Comment: When I run the `ps` command to find out the `pid` of `worker.py`, it turns out that the process doesn't exist. Could that be the reason why `master.py` hangs? Please see the updated post

Comment: Oh, perhaps you need to add `server.join()` at the bottom of `worker.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectivity issue here had two causes:

1. When you connect to a gRPC session (actually on the first `Session.run()` call) TensorFlow blocks until it gets a response from all of the tasks in the cluster.
2. The `worker.py` scripts exited immediately after creating a `tf.train.Server`.

If you have a script that starts a [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Server) (e.g., called `server`) and does nothing else, remember to call [`server.join()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Server.join) as the last statement in your script.